# (Familier) (Populaire) (Argot) - what's the difference?

Tags: sens

[faire tourner en bourrique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_tourner_en_bourrique)

For example, this locution is labelled as *Populaire*, but I don't quite understand how words and locutions in *Populaire* differ from those in *Familier* or *Argot*. I thought that all these three mean they are used casually, but is there more concrete difference?

Is the *Populaire* "faire tourner en bourrique" supposed to be used by what kind of people or in what kind of situation?

Answer (score 9):

*Populaire*, when it refers to the level of language, means that it is typically used by lower social classes.

*Argot* denotes a vocabulary used originally by the underworld (in the sense of thieves, prostitutes, etc.). It can be used by other social groups but will still be rated negatively as language used by "bad boys/girls".

*Familier* means it is a level of language used typically among interlocutors sharing a high level of intimacy (family members, friends), but not in eg. the press, academic writing, professional contexts, etc.

Note that if you compare similar entries in multiple dictionaries, you will see that the border between *familier* and *populaire* is rather thin and that a same word can be rated either as *familier* or *popular* in different sources (eg the word *tronche* is rated as *populaire* by the TLFi and as *familier* by the Wiktionary).

Comment: Thank you. So as a non-native university student aged 22, should I avoid using Populaire and Argot words, even among my friends? Should I keep words in these two categories to a knowing-them-but-not-using-them-myself level?

Comment: Feel free to use them with your friends, especially among students, it will not be frowned upon. But refrain to use them if you talk to a professor or university staff (using a *populaire* word may be seen as weird at best, impolite at worst. *Argot* is a big no then).

Comment: How about using Familier words to a professor or university staff? And on the other hand, how about using Soutenu and Literale words to a professor or university staff?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you are unsure, just stick to "standard" words... It all depends on the context: if you just have an informal, friendly chat after a class, with a professor you know a bit (eg he knows you by your first name), very common and trivial *familier* words (eg. *sous* for *money*) can be ok, but not if you have a more formal academic interaction, eg if you are taking an oral exam with them.  Using *soutenu* or *literary* words may sound a bit weird in the same informal chat  - but definitely not impolite. In an an oral exam, it would definely be ok - it may even impress them !

Comment: So in a French-speaking proficiency exam (speaking in front of interviewers for them to judge my speaking skills), should I avoid using (Familier) (Populaire) (Argot) and just stick to (Standard), occasionally mixing (Soutenu) (Literary)?

Comment: Standard will fit all purposes. I can only imagine familier/argot/populaire would be ok only if you are judged on the basis of a "role-play" assessment, eg if you need to show your language skills by playing a dialogue between eg a a child and his mother or father.

Comment: @Dasshoes Greg's advice encompasses a sound notion: you have to cry with the pack as the familiar adage says; nevertheless, his advice is basically founded on a double standard: you find yourself using words, not for what they confer in themselves but for what they confer to a particular group of people. Don't forget that repeated use of word is habit forming: you'll never use as naturally words you are not used to, words with a sound and feel that remain uncertain to you. Therefore use the word that seems right to you!

Answer (score 3):

In French like in English, the formality of a word, or lack of, can and often do  evolve during the time. Its popularity too. The TLFi sometimes considers informal what is mainstream today.

In any case, while it is useful to know the various ways to say something in French, it is better to stick the the standard way until you are very familiar with the language level of the variants and you know exactly what levels are expected during a conversation.

A typical word English speaking people have often an issue translating to French is "**guy**".

Here are various ways to translate it:

- *Un **individu*** : formal
- *Une **personne*** : standard
- *Un **monsieur*** : often *familier*, child language (*m'sieu*)
- *Un **mec*** : used to be *argot*, is now *familier*
- *Un **gonze*** : *argot*, outdated
- *Un **type*** : *familier*
- *Un **keum*** : *argot* (*verlan*)

Very often, I have heard foreigners using ***type*** or ***mec*** (because they have ***guy*** which is colloquial in mind) in situations where native speakers won't have used these words but just ***personne***.

I guess this is somewhat similar to a non native English speaker writing ***I wanna*** in an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

To the sound definition of the three terms given in this [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37004/17649) I'll add the following appreciations. First, whether "familier" (informel), "populaire" or "argot" the three registers carry with them a certain degree of vulgarity; ranking in increasing degree of vulgarity we find "familier", "populaire", "argot". Second, one must keep in mind that "argot", if sometimes translated as "slang", does not correspond most of the time to English slang (as this [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37004/17649) clearly allows to make out); "argot" is of a register comparatively more vulgar than "slang", except for what is called "coarse slang" and it is comparatively much less acceptable in French than English slang is in English.

Comment: The level of vulgarity is not (necessarily) related to the fact a word is *familier*, *informel* or *argot*. For example *bagnole* or *toubib* are *argot* but not vulgar.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne suis pas d'accord, je pense bien sûr que ces mots sont loin d'être aussi vulgaire que d'autres, il ne sont que légèrement vulgaires et dans certain on pourrait même négliger le côté vulgaire et il ne sont plus que très ordinaires; d'après ma perception « toubib » l'est beaucoup moins que « bagnole » mais il n'en reste pas moins que la neutralité du mot « voiture » a disparu; on émet un jugement sur la chose qu'est la voiture, c'est une chose de peu, plutôt méprisable et ça c'est une notion étrangère à la chose  elle-même.

Comment: *Mon toubib adore les belles bagnoles*... Où se niche la vulgarité ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il y a un principe auquel je suis arrivé, que l'on ne mentionne jamais et auquel je crois dur comme fer et c'est qu'un mot n'est jamais ni plus vulgaire ni moins vulgaire que la partie de la population qui l'emploie; il ne peut y avoir dans un mot plus ou moins de vulgarité que ce que les gens qui l'utilisent mettent dedans. La vulgarité dans ces deux mots vient donc du monde qui les utilise, auquel on est exposé dans la vie de tous les jours et dans les œuvres et ouvrages de toutes sortes. C'est là que se niche cette vulgarité et c'est ça qui est difficile à évaluer. (champ 1)

Comment: @jlliagre Vous ne trouvez pas ces mots vulgaires (en fait, je trouve "toubib" presque pas vulgaire), mais il n'y a là qu'une question de variation dans les perceptions individuelles; peu importe que je trouve plus ou moins de vulgarité. Il est certain que vous devez trouver certaines formes vulgaires; choisissez la pire dans cette catégorie et cherchez où se niche la vulgarité; malgré votre conviction et un avis général assez uniforme vous serez dans le même embarras que moi; qu'est-ce qui la fait vulgaire ? Il vous faudra dire autre chose que « C'est l'avis de tout le monde. ». (fin)